# How fix two pages render in ternary navigation return

Tags: reactjs, firebase, conditional-statements, persistent, rerender

I'm trying to implement a persistent login session in react with firebase, it works kind of good, but i have a problem with the initial state and the re-render of the component, the initial state of `currentUser` it's `null` then the useEffect from the `useAuth` component renders and check if it's a logged user, and set the `currentUser`to a truthy value.

useAuth component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rerendered useAuth");

    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("We are authenticated now!");
        setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        console.log("The user is not logged!");
        setCurrentUser(null);
      }
    });
    // Cleanup subscription on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Ternary return in navigation:

```
function MainNavigator() {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      initialRouteName={RoutesEnum.landing}
    >
      {currentUser ? (     // null at first, then truthy
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            name={RoutesEnum.tabNavigator}
            component={TabNavigator}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name={RoutesEnum.stories} component={Stories} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name={RoutesEnum.landing} component={Landing} />
          <Stack.Screen name={RoutesEnum.login} component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name={RoutesEnum.register} component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name={RoutesEnum.myAccount} component={MyAccount} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name={RoutesEnum.forgotPassword}
            component={ResetPassword}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The problem:

At the first renders the landing page (for a few milliseconds) because the initial state its `null`, then renders the useAuth and with the useEffect logs the user, and then navigates to the home.

How can i fix this issue that renders the two screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your "useAuth" hook returns a `loading` prop, it generally should. Then youll have something like this:

```js
const { currentUser, loading } = useAuth();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

if (loading) return null;

return (
// ... rest of your code
```

You can also do `if (loading) return <LoadingPage/>` if you build a component like that out